# How do I read a double value using StreamReader?

Tags: c#

I'm trying to read from a txt file into an array. I wrote everything to read as an integer, however I misread the info and need to be able to account for decimals as well. How can I change the code below to allow for decimals?

I'm new to C# but I haven't been able to figure this out. If I just switch int to double, I get the error "cannot implicitly convert type int to double".

```
            StreamReader ifile;
            ifile = File.OpenText("sales.txt");
            int count = 0;
            string str = "";
            //Populating the array
            while (ifile.EndOfStream == false)
            {
                str = ifile.ReadLine();
                list[count] = decimal.Parse(str);
                count++;
            }
            // Display the contents of the array
            foreach (decimal val in list)
            {
                listBoxSales.Items.Add(val);
            }

            int Average;
            Average = average(list);
            labelAvgsales.Text = Average.ToString();
```

I just need to pull numbers into an array list. The code above works to pull integers, but obviously fails when there are integers in the list stating "input string was not in a correct format".

Update: decimals no longer error out using the code above. Second part I hoped to figure out on my own is calling info from the array.

The below worked previously, but after switching to allow decimals it errors out. I tried switching int to decimal in the below but I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong.

```
private int average(int[] numList)
        {
            int avg;
            int total = 0;
            for (int i = 0; i < numList.Length; i++)
            {
                total += numList[i];
            }
            avg = total / numList.Length;
            return avg;
        }
```

Comment: Change `int.Parse(str);` to `decimal.Parse(str)` if it's money or `double.Parse(str);` if not money. Make sure to change `list` to the same type.

Comment: First, if `list` is just an `ArrayList`, you should change it to a generic `List<T>`, and make `T` an appropriate type representative of what's in your test file. Integer values can be represented as decimals too, so does it matter to you what the data type is in `list`? If not, you could change your `list` to a `List<decimal>` and then use `decimal.Parse()` instead of `int.Parse()`. If you want the data types to be mixed, you'll have to use a `List<object>`, then use some smart parsing logic (try `int` first, if that fails, try `decimal`, etc.).

Comment: Right now it's hard to provide a valid solution because there are parts of your code we can't see the definitions for (`list`, for example). With a better [mcve] we can provide a better answer.

Comment: CodingYoshi's suggestion worked. The second part to this I hoped I could figure out once that was fixed but I guess not. Updating post with the other info.

Comment: Disregard, I figured it out. Thanks CodingYoshi for the suggestion. If you want to post an answer I'll mark it as accepted.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `decimal.Parse`:

```
    var x = "1";
    var y = "1.1";
    Console.WriteLine(decimal.Parse(x));
    Console.WriteLine(decimal.Parse(y));
```

Here's a dotnetfiddle showing how to do this: https://dotnetfiddle.net/mUB8iz

Answer (score 0):

C# is type safe programming language,

You could use the  ArrayList  class is not type-safe because it can store any object, which means you can do something like the following:

```
 var integers = new  ArrayList();
 while (ifile.EndOfStream == false)
 {
 str = ifile.ReadLine();
 integers.Add(decimal.Parse(str));
 }
```

and go through as following.